# Error BC30456: 'text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'

Tags: vb.net, iis

I need to move website from remote server to local IIS (Windows 7 Enterprise). Everything works except some links, error message:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.
```

Source:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim data1 = FormView1.FindControl("label18")
    Dim data2 = FormView1.FindControl("label19")
    Dim data3 = FormView1.FindControl("label20")
    Dim data4 = FormView1.FindControl("label21")
    Dim data5 = FormView1.FindControl("label22")
    data1.text = Session("rok")
```

Last line is highlighted in error message.

When I use "View in Browser" in Visual Web Developer 2008 everything works. What I need to run this site with no errors on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to a label then you have access to the `Text` property.

```
Dim data1 = TryCast(FormView1.FindControl("label18"), Label)
If Not data1 Is Nothing Then data1.Text = Session("rok")
```

data1 = `Nothing` if it does not convert.

Comment: It works, thanks. For my curiosity - why I don't need to do this when launching from Visual Web Developer or on remote server?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim data1 = CType(FormView1.FindControl("label18"), Label).text= Session("rok")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).